# When using AFJSONRequestOperation, why must I also setDefaultHeader to application/json?

Tags: objective-c, json, afnetworking

From the AFNetworking FAQ:

> **Why don't I get JSON / XML / Property List in my HTTP client callbacks?**
>
> ...
>
> To work with JSON data, for example, do `[client registerHTTPOperationClass:[AFJSONRequestOperation class]]` and `[client setDefaultHeader:@"Accept" value:@"application/json"]` when initializing the HTTP client.

If I'm using `AFJSONRequestOperation`, doesn't that imply I only want to accept application/json? You'd think AFNetworking would automatically set the Accept header to application/json.

I assume there's a good reason it doesn't...but what could that reason be? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The `setDefaultHeader:` is the header for your requests. You could use some custom or derived  class as the default class, which could do JSON but how is `AFHTTPClient` going to know that.

Comment: "how is AFHTTPClient going to know that" Maybe I'm not understanding setDefaultHeader, but if I'm registering AFJSONRequestOperation with the AFHTTPClient, then it knows I want to accept JSON, correct?